# Variable unexpectedly returning null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, iteration

I am iterating through a list to get an item which has bool value *false*.

**Class**:

```
class Words {
  String alphabet;
  String word;
  String wordtype;
  String image;
  bool used;

  Words({
    required this.alphabet,
    required this.word,
    required this.wordtype,
    required this.image,
    required this.used,
  });
}
```

The following is the sample data being used

```
List<Words> initData = [
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'apple',
        wordtype: 'fruit',
        image: 'assets/res/apple.jpg',
        used: false),
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'ant',
        wordtype: 'insect',
        image: 'assets/res/ant.jpg',
        used: false),
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'axe',
        wordtype: 'object',
        image: 'assets/res/axe.jpg',
        used: false),
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'arrow',
        wordtype: 'object',
        image: 'assets/res/arrow.jpg',
        used: false),
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'airplane',
        wordtype: 'object',
        image: 'assets/res/airplane.jpg',
        used: false),
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'anchor',
        wordtype: 'object',
        image: 'assets/res/anchor.jpg',
        used: false),
    Words(
        alphabet: 'a',
        word: 'alligator',
        wordtype: 'animal',
        image: 'assets/res/alligator.jpg',
        used: false),
  ];
```

Calling **Widget**

```
class WordsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final homeCtrl = Get.find<HomeController>();
  WordsWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(homeCtrl.nextWord());
    return Container();
  }
}
```

The following function iterates, if all words have been used it resets them and iterates again.

**Functions:**

```
  nextWord() {
    Words nextword =
        Words(alphabet: '', word: '', wordtype: '', image: '', used: false);
    bool found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i].used == false && found != true) {
        nextword = words[i];
        words[i].used = true;
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found == false) {
      print("resetting");
      resetWords();
    } else {
      print("Found = true so now returning");
      print(nextword.word);
      return nextword.word;
    }
  }

  void resetWords() {
    for (var a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
      words[a].used = false;
    }
    nextWord();
  }
```

The above works fine till it resets. After reset even though print above return shows the value but when I print the same on calling widget it returns null. The following is the output to illustrate the issue.

```
flutter: Found = true so now returning
2    flutter: arrow
flutter: Found = true so now returning
2    flutter: airplane
flutter: Found = true so now returning
2    flutter: anchor
flutter: Found = true so now returning
2    flutter: alligator
flutter: resetting
flutter: Found = true so now returning
flutter: apple
flutter: null
```

As you can see from above, after the word alligator it resets it self and sets used = false for all words. It then searches for the next word in iteration and it has found the word apple but the widget which called the function still returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh added.

Comment: @derpirscher I have already added some example data for words.

Comment: If that is really your data and your algorithm, I don't get your output, because the first word returned should be apple ... And what does that `2` in your ouput mean, why is it only present at the first lines? Are there multiple threads or processes calling that method? Furthermore that `null` output cannot possibly result from `print(nextword.word)` because there must be a `"Found = true so now returning"` before

Comment: Which function is returning `null`?   Do you mean that something is *printing* `null`?  And if so, what?  Where is that code?

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to your problem, but `if (words[i].used == false && found != true)` makes my head hurt.  They're both non-nullable `bool`s, so just use `if (!words[i].used && !found)`.  Better yet, use `if (!words[i].used) { ... found = true; break; }`

Comment: The have pasted the log towards the end of the word list to keep it short here. The print is done at two places because of which it shows 2. One is before return and the other is by the widget which was calling this function. So in all words except 'apple' which is first word it shows 2, because the output is 2 times. But for the word apple, the function returns apple but when the calling widget prints the output it shows null.

Comment: @jamesdlin I have added the calling widget code. It was a simple print to see the output.

Comment: Well, `nextWord` neglects to return a value along the resetting path, so it implicitly returns `null` to the caller.  You really should fix your functions to always declare return types so that the analyzer can help you catch mistakes like that.

Comment: @jamesdlin could you please explain a little how does it neglect to return a value on resetting path and how to fix it. Would really appreciate it :) Thank you

Comment: In case you don't find a word, you are just calling `resetWords` but not returing anything. Eventhough `resetWords` calls `nextWord` again, it doesn't return its result. BTW with this construct you will get an infinite recursion, if your initial `words` array is empty ...

Comment: @derpirscher please correct me if I am wrong, but when resetWords calls nextWord doesn't the else part of the if (found == false) get executed? I mean it does print 'Found = true so now returning'.

Comment: yes it does, but the result of that "inner" call of `nextWord` isn't used anywhere and therefore lost.

Comment: @derpirscher please could you kindly suggest a fix code?

Comment: If that code does not throw bunches of warnings, please configure your compiler and linter so it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with your current code

1. It will run into an infinite recursion (and thus an exception) if your list of `words` is empty.
2. In case, you didn't find a usable word in your `for` loop you don't return anything ...

```
nextWord() {

  // if there are no available words, don't need to do anything
  if (words.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    //when you found an unused word, set the flag and return the word
    if (!words[i].used) {
      words[i].used = true;
      return words[i].word;
    }
  }

  //in case you didn't find anything, return the result of resetWords
  return resetWords();
}


resetWords() {
  //reset the flags
  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i].used = false;
  }

  //and call nextWord again, and return its result
  return nextWord();
}
```